# Javascript merge 2 arrays on index 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, merge

i would like to merge array a in array b on index 2.

let a = [1,2,7,8,9,10];
let b = [3,4,5,6];

How should i write my code?

Tia

Comment: You can find more posts [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=merge+2+arrays+by+index+js+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIN767IN767&sxsrf=ALeKk03DEFmJe4QTbBpr_cALARXz3pkc2w:1583231736890&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5xJjqjf7nAhW9_XMBHQNqD8IQrQIoBDACegQIAhAO&biw=2560&bih=1299)

Comment: It's not clear. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use the splice method.

```js
let a = [1,2,7,8,9,10]; 
let b = [3,4,5,6];

b.splice(2, 0, ...a);

console.log(b);
```